# Ionic - Chaining promises only proceed when promise resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, promise

What I'm trying to do is I want chaining promises only proceed to next **.then** after promise is resolve. This is what I'm did:

Javascript:

```
var checking = false;
  var defer = $q.defer();
  var promise = defer.promise;

  promise.then(function(){
      a();
  })

  .then(function(){
      b();
  })

  .then(function(){
      c();
  })

  if(!checking)
        defer.resolve('Ok');


var a = function(){
    console.log("function a");
};

var b = function(){

    var def = $q.defer();

    $ionicPopup.show({
        title: 'Click cancel for reject promise and OK for resolve promise.',
        buttons: [
                {
                  text: '<b>Cancel</b>',
                  type: 'button-light',
                  onTap: function(e) {
                        def.resolve("resolve");
                        return;
                    }
                },
                {
                  text: '<b>OK</b>',
                  type: 'button-positive',
                  onTap: function(e) {
                      def.reject("reject");
                  }
                }
              ]
            }).then(function(res) {

            });

    return def.promise;
};

var c = function(){
    console.log("function c");
};
```

Based on the code above, what I'm trying to do, when it reached to **function b**, its only proceed when user click on **OK** or **Cancel** at ionicPopup.

Here is the **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/aishahismail/pen/RrvbrZ)**. Thanks for help.

Comment: you're not returning anything in the `.then`s ... `return b()`  `return c()` etc

Comment: see updated [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZVYZQ)

Comment: yeah you're right. Thanks so much.